# Python: How to print certain values from a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, printing

I got a dictionary `self.ticketDict1` which looks like this.

```
2457 : {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Kunde', 
'ticket-closed': True, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 64183, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 64183, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 16, 5, 0, 179351, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 28, 13, 32, 47, 523975, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 9, 16, 8, 16, 726823, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}

2458 : {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Kunde', 
'ticket-closed': True, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 77779, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 77779, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 15, 12, 53, 29570, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}

2459 : {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Kunde', 
'ticket-closed': True, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 94126, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'W\xfcnschenswert')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 94126, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 14, 47, 28, 916677, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}
```

Now I want to print all calendarweeks from the very first `status-events` value of each item.

I've tried it this way:

```
for i in self.ticketDict1:
      print i['status-events'][0][0].isocalendar()[1]
```

But I always get this Error:

```
File "/media/sf_Projects/Ticketauswertung/Converting.py", line 86, in ConvertData
print i['status-events'][0][0].isocalendar()[1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

EDIT:
If I print my dictionary this way:

```
for i in self.ticketDict1:
            print i, ' : ', self.ticketDict1[i]
            print '\n'
```

I get this result:

```
2556  :  {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 30, 59, 547747, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 30, 59, 547747, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}


2557  :  {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 32, 37, 491657, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 32, 37, 491657, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}


2558  :  {'origin': u'HW', 'department': u'Intern', 'ticket-closed': False, 'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 33, 51, 29451, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'Wichtig')], 'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 16, 33, 51, 29451, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "CEST" 2:00:00>), u'new')]}
```

As you can see there is nothing wrong with my dictionary.

Comment: I feel the first element of one of your `'status-events'` is an `int` data type and not `date`

Comment: (datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 64183, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>)

Comment: looks like a datetime to me.

Comment: Is your program printing some data before throwing the error and could you add another `print statement` before the current `print statement` that is this statement `print i['status-events'][0][0],"Checking"`

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
>>> x = {'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 27, 16, 53, 55, 64183, None), u'new'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 16, 5, 0, 179351, None), u'closed'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 28, 13, 32, 47, 523975, None), u'closed'), 
(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 9, 16, 8, 16, 726823, None), u'closed')]}
>>> x['status-events'][0][0].isocalendar()
(2015, 18, 1)
>>> x['status-events'][0][0].isocalendar()[1]
18
```

It's because you are looping through self.TicketDict1, which is going to give you each key in the dictionary. What you want is this:

```
for i in self.TicketDict1['statusevents'].values():
    i[0][0].isocalendar()[1]
```

I'm not sure what `2457` is (I'm assuming a colon is missing, and it should say `2457:`), so you might want this instead:

```
for i in self.TicketDict1[2457]['statusevents'].values():
    i[0][0].isocalendar()[1]
```

You also want to use dictionary.values() to get the values, as opposed to the keys. For example:

```
x = {1:'one', 2:'two'}

for i in x.values():
    print i

>>> one
>>> two
```

while:

```
x = {1:'one', 2:'two'}

for i in x:
    print i

>>> 1
>>> 2
```

As you loop your code how it is currently written, you are getting the keys. The error is probably coming from an attempt to retrieve items from one of the keys in your dictionary, eg. `2457['status-events'][0][0].isocalendar()[1]` will throw an error.

Note:

```
x = {1:'one', 2:'two'}

for i in x:
    print i[1]

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I get the same error with your code. Btw: I've edited my question and added some information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it by myself. Nevertheless thanks for the quick questions!

Code:

```
for i in self.ticketDict1:
        for j,k in self.ticketDict1[i]['status-events']:
            print i, ' : ', j.isocalendar()[1]
            break
```

Result:

```
1459  :  5
1977  :  16
1978  :  16
1979  :  16
2498  :  29
3011  :  44
2500  :  29
3013  :  45
```

Comment: That will work. You can simplify this further by using `for j in self.ticketDict1[i]['status-events'].values():`. Also, why did you decide to put a `break` there?

Comment: i've put `break` in there because I only need the first element of `status-events` and not all of them.